# Samsung Email Client

Tags: onion-routing, android, email, server, settings

I have tor running through Termux on my phone and I was able to set up Firefox Android to use that tor connection without any problems.  Now, I'd like to be able to use the stock Samsung Email Client to send & receive email in the same manner.  I know that in order to do that, I'll need to make adjustments in the email server settings as shown in the enclosed screenshot.  Would anyone happen to know what the settings are in order to accomplish that end?  Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.[image]

Comment: What do you mean by you got tor running through termux? Do you mean you're running the standard tor daemon in the termux environment? If so, then you probably need to set your application to use tor's SOCKS proxy, but the Samsung app probably doesn't have this feature.

Comment: I mean that I installed tor in Termux by typing 'pkg install tor' then I press 'enter.'  Then, I simply type 'tor' and press 'enter' and tor then runs from the Termux environment.  So far, I have been able to adjust the server settings in Firefox Android to use that same connection to tor that I established in the Termux environment.  I'd like to do the same thing with the stock Samsung Android email app that came with the phone.  Is such a thing possible?

Comment: How did you do it in Firefox? By setting a SOCKS proxy?

Comment: In 'about:config,' I changed the following values: network.proxy.http - 127.0.0.1 network.proxy.http_port - 8118 network.proxy.socks - 127.0.0.1 network.proxy.socks_port - 9050 network.proxy.socks_remote_dns - true 
network.proxy.type - 1

Comment: I then restarted Firefox, of course.

Comment: Okay, unless the Samsung app has an option to set the SOCKS proxy, you cannot use this method to have the app use Tor. Instead, you may want to look into [Orbot](https://guardianproject.info/apps/org.torproject.android/).

Comment: Alright then, thanks for your help.